# node-gyp error in travis build for node 4.0 & 4.1

Tags: node.js, travis-ci, bcrypt

When I run a travis build, I get the following error when it attempts to run node-gyp on node version 4.0 and 4.1.
0.12 and lower don't seem to have these issues and build fine. I'm not sure if its a compiler issue here?

```
> bcrypt@0.8.5 install /home/travis/build/me/api/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild
make: Entering directory `/home/travis/build/me/api/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
In file included from /home/travis/.node-gyp/4.1.2/include/node/node.h:42:0,
                 from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:24,
                 from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
/home/travis/.node-gyp/4.1.2/include/node/v8.h:336:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
/home/travis/.node-gyp/4.1.2/include/node/v8.h:469:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
/home/travis/.node-gyp/4.1.2/include/node/v8.h:852:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:184:0,
                 from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:13:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:16:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:19:12: error: ‘Maybe’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:24:12: error: ‘Maybe’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:31:1: error: ‘MaybeLocal’ does 
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:59:0,
                 from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:189,
                 from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:18:1: error: ‘return_t’ in ‘struct Nan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Boolean>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:19:1: error: ‘return_t’ in ‘struct Nan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Number>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:20:1: error: ‘return_t’ in ‘struct Nan::imp::ToFactory<v8::String>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:21:1: error: ‘return_t’ in ‘struct Nan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Object>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:22:1: error: ‘return_t’ in ‘struct Nan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Integer>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:23:1: error: ‘return_t’ in ‘struct Nan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Uint32>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:24:1: error: ‘return_t’ in ‘struct Nan::imp::ToFactory<v8::Int32>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:34:1: error: ‘return_t’ in ‘struct Nan::imp::ToFactory<bool>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:35:1: error: ‘return_t’ in ‘struct Nan::imp::ToFactory<double>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:36:1: error: ‘return_t’ in ‘struct Nan::imp::ToFactory<long int>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:37:1: error: ‘return_t’ in ‘struct Nan::imp::ToFactory<unsigned int>’ does not name a type
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:38:1: error: ‘return_t’ in ‘struct Nan::imp::ToFactory<int>’ does not name a type
In file included from ../node_modules/nan/nan.h:190:0,
                 from ../src/bcrypt_node.cc:1:
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h: In function ‘v8::Local<T> Nan::imp::To(v8::Local<v8::Integer>) [with T = v8::Integer]’:
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:21:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘To(v8::Local<v8::Integer>&)’
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:21:32: note: candidate is:
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:53:38: note: template<class T> typename Nan::imp::ToFactory::return_t Nan::To(v8::Local<v8::Value>)
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h: In function ‘v8::Local<T> Nan::imp::To(v8::Local<v8::Integer>) [with T = v8::Int32]’:
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:28:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘To(v8::Local<v8::Integer>&)’
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:28:30: note: candidate is:
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:53:38: note: template<class T> typename Nan::imp::ToFactory::return_t Nan::To(v8::Local<v8::Value>)
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h: In function ‘v8::Local<T> Nan::imp::To(v8::Local<v8::Integer>) [with T = v8::Uint32]’:
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:35:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘To(v8::Local<v8::Integer>&)’
../node_modules/nan/nan_new.h:35:31: note: candidate is:
../node_modules/nan/nan_converters.h:53:38: note: template<class T> typename Nan::imp::ToFactory::return_t Nan::To(v8::Local<v8::Value>)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yeah I had a similar issue when migrating from 0.12.x

try adding

```
language: node_js
node_js:
 - "4.2.4"
env:
 - CXX=g++-4.8
addons:
 apt:
  sources:
   - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
  packages:
   - g++-4.8
```

to your travis config